# Visualize memory areas JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any tool sort of thing, from where we can see, for a given java source code, where variables, references, objects, static fields resides in JVM.

Comment: Like a debugger? What exactly do you mean by "where ... resides in JVM?"

Comment: I'm talking about memory areas.From the title of the ques. you can see that.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the variable and a lot more in [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) - Java Virtual Machine Monitoring, Troubleshooting, and Profiling Tool. You can see threads, garbage collection, heap memory and more. Give it a try!